# Upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS breaks Akonadi and thus KMail

Tags: kubuntu, mysql, kmail, akonadi

I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS from 19.10. Now Kmail is broken because Akonadi won't run.

`akonadictl start` gives the following but I want to call attention to the ninth line which I've isolated below ("**The line in question:**"),

```
~$ akonadictl start
Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
~$ org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Starting up the Akonadi Server...
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: database server stopped unexpectedly
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Database process exited unexpectedly during initial connection!
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: executable: "/usr/sbin/mysqld-akonadi"
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: arguments: ("--defaults-file=/home/panczol/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf", "--datadir=/home/panczol/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/", "--socket=/run/user/1000/akonadi/mysql.socket", "--pid-file=/run/user/1000/akonadi/mysql.pid")
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: stdout: ""
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: stderr: "mysqld-akonadi: [ERROR] Could not open required defaults file: /home/panczol/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf\nmysqld-akonadi: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!\n"
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: exit code: 1
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: process error: "Unknown error"
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Failed to remove runtime connection config file
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Shutting down AkonadiServer...
org.kde.pim.akonadicontrol: Application '/usr/bin/akonadiserver' exited normally...
```

**The line in question:**

```
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: stderr: "mysqld-akonadi: [ERROR] Could not open required defaults file: /home/panczol/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf\nmysqld-akonadi: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!\n"
```

Note that the filename `mysql.conf\nmysqld-akonadi` has an embedded newline suggesting a error in some script.

The file `/home/panczol/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf` exists.

How to correct this? A Google search hadn't offered anything I found responsive (I may be asking the wrong questions).

Comment: This is usually due to a permissions issue involving AppArmor. Try this: `sudo aa-complain /usr/bin/akonadiserver`. This will change the enforcement mode *just* for the application. If it works, then you know there's a setting in AppArmor that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Apparmor was not installed.

Comment: AppArmor now installed. Running aa-complain gives the message "Profile for /usr/bin/akonadiserver not found, skipping". akonaditctl start returns the error messages as given in the posting.

Comment: The problem WAS due to permissions involving AppArmor. The quick-and-dirty fix: sudo systemctl disable apparmor then reboot.