# Akonadi on KDE can't start due to "Unknown error" and I can't update MariaDB

Tags: kde, mysql, mariadb, kmail, akonadi

Konact / KMail does not want to start anymore, because Akonadi fails. I am not able to start akonadi

```
~$ akonadictl --verbose start
Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Starting up the Akonadi Server...
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Found mysql_install_db:  "/usr/bin/mysql_install_db"
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Found mysqlcheck:  "/usr/bin/mysqlcheck"
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Using mysqld: "/usr/sbin/mysqld-akonadi"
org.kde.pim.akonadicontrol: Service ":1.89" owner changed from "" to ":1.89"
org.kde.pim.akonadicontrol: Service ":1.90" owner changed from "" to ":1.90"
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: mysqld reports version 10.3.34 (MariaDB)
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Executing: "/usr/sbin/mysqld-akonadi" "--defaults-file=/home/raeg/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf --datadir=/home/raeg/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/ --socket=/run/user/1000/akonadi/mysql.socket --pid-file=/run/user/1000/akonadi/mysql.pid"
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: database server stopped unexpectedly
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Database process exited unexpectedly during initial connection!
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: executable: "/usr/sbin/mysqld-akonadi"
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: arguments: ("--defaults-file=/home/raeg/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf", "--datadir=/home/raeg/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/", "--socket=/run/user/1000/akonadi/mysql.socket", "--pid-file=/run/user/1000/akonadi/mysql.pid")
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: stdout: ""
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: stderr: "2022-05-10 15:12:03 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld-akonadi (mysqld 10.3.34-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 7312 ...\n"
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: exit code: 1
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: process error: "Unknown error"
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: terminating connection threads
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: terminating service threads
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: stopping db process
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Failed to remove runtime connection config file
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Shutting down AkonadiServer...
org.kde.pim.akonadicontrol: Service ":1.90" owner changed from ":1.90" to ""
org.kde.pim.akonadicontrol: Application '/usr/bin/akonadiserver' exited normally...
```

#### Trying to update MariaDB

I read, that I should update MariaDB, but I do not know how.

```
~$ sudo systemctl restart mariadb
Failed to restart mariadb.service: Unit mariadb.service not found.
~$ sudo mysql_upgrade
Reading datadir from the MariaDB server failed. Got the following error when executing the 'mysql' command line client
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
~$ sudo mariadb-upgrade
sudo: mariadb-upgrade: Command not found
~$ mariadb --version
mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.34-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

Then I [ran](https://www.linuxcapable.com/install-upgrade-mariadb-10-8-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/)

```
curl -LsS https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb_repo_setup | sudo bash -s -- --mariadb-server-version=10.8
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
~$ mariadb --version
mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.34-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

But as one can see, that did not change much.

I read, https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=184192, that the update to MariaDB version 10 might be the problem. It suggests to downgrade and then do some stuff and then upgrade again. However, that article is from 2014, so I am not sure that it still applies.

#### AppArmor

According to [Upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS breaks Akonadi and thus KMail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1313082/upgrade-to-ubuntu-20-04-2-lts-breaks-akonadi-and-thus-kmail) it might be an issue with apparmor, so I ran

```
sudo systemctl disable apparmor
```

and rebooted, but that did not help.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why, but this helped:

1. I renamed `~/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf` to `~/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf_backup`.
2. Then I restarted akonadi with `akonadictl start`.

The file `mysql.conf` was recreated (identical to the original file `mysql.conf_backup`) and now everything works again.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the answer of Make42, but it did not work at first. Then I edited `/root/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf` and added the line

```
user=root
```

in the `[mysqld]` section. Then `akonadictl start` worked.